# Simple Email Message to an 0365 email Acccount

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I know that the Send-MailMessage ins powershell is already obsolete based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0uln.png)

Is there any alternate way to send email message? its fine if there is no attachment, just an email message that successfully received by recipient like Hello World? I will appreciate any sample or assistance. I'm still learning PowerShell.

I've tried using the Mimekit and MailKit but it seems it doesn't work for me. Maybe there is other way which is much simpler. Thank you in advance guys

Comment: How will you be sending the email? Do you have access to submit directly to a local SMTP server or will you be using a web-based service?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it will be a web based service such as 0365 we already moved everything to cloud and we don't have local SMTP Server. I will appreciate if you can shed me some light or pointing to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Youtube Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy5vs0gEei0
Mimekit and Mailkit works for me fine.
Below the Example from the Youtube Video, hope it will help you

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\MailKit\mimekit.3.4.2\lib\netstandard2.0\MimeKit.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\MailKit\mailkit.3.4.2\lib\netstandard2.0\MailKit.dll"

$SMTP = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient
$Message = New-Object MimeKit.MimeMessage
$Builder = New-Object MimeKit.BodyBuilder

# Create Credentials File
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path C:\Temp\SendMail.xml
$Account = Import-Clixml -Path C:\Temp\SendMail.xml

$Message.From.Add("from@from.com")
$Message.To.Add("to@to.com")
$Message.Subject = "Test Message"
$Builder.TextBody = "This is a test Email message"
$Message.Body = $Builder.ToMessageBody()
$SMTP.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, $false) 
$SMTP.Authenticate($Account) 
$SMTP.Send($Message) 
$SMTP.Disconnect($true) 
$SMTP.Dispose()
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting,

MethodInvocationException:

$SMTP.Authenticate($Account)

Exception calling "Authenticate" with "1" argument(s): "535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. 


MethodInvocationException:

$SMTP.Send($Message)

Exception calling "Authenticate" with "1" argument(s): "535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. 

Any idea? I'm 100% sure that I put the correct username and password